Get results in a delimited format
I'm attempting to setup a spreadsheet, that when PackNum is entered all the offers for that PackNum will be put in the Offer cell in a delimited format.
For example:
I enter Packnumber 600035 in the spreadsheet
I'd like all the offers delimited in column B

Source:

Outcome I'd like

I thought to use Findfirst but realized it will only give me the first result and not formatted how I want.
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim UpsellWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Deletes As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim UpsellData As DAO.Recordset
    
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A500")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing And Range("A2").Value > 100 Then
    'When cell changes run program
        
        'Recordsets
        Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("<datapool path>\db.accdb")
        Set UpsellData = db.OpenRecordset("UpsellDeletePool")
        'Workbooks
        Set UpsellWB = Workbooks.Open("<spreadsheet path>\Upsell.xlsm")
        'Worksheets
        Set Deletes = UpsellWB.Worksheets("Deletes")
        'set lrow
        lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'With Deletes
    'For I = 2 To lrow
    'UpsellData.FindFirst ("[Packnum]= '" & Deletes.Range("A" & I).Value & "'")
    '        Deletes.Range("B" & I).Value = UpsellData.Fields("[Offer]").Value
    'Next I
    'End With
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Else
    
    End If
    
    'Closing Procedure
    Set db = Nothing
    Set UpsellData = Nothing
    Set UpsellWB = Nothing
    Set Deletes = Nothing
End Sub

Data:
I have been playing around with two options.
One option is to use a query in my Access database as a record set to pull the data.
The other option is that I have that same record set setup as a table on a worksheet named DeletePool which updates everytime you open the workbook.

Where are data to concatenate?

I have been playing around with two options. One option was to use a query in my access database as a record set to pull the data. The other option is that I have that same record set setup as a table on a worksheet named DeletePool which updates everytime you open the workbook.

As of the second variant pls. see my answer.

@Blackcat thanks! I'm messing around with this formula to try to make it work for what I'm trying to do. Really appreciate it! Thank you!

With Excel formula this can be achieved if the data are on an Excel sheet.
Formula in cell H1
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B15,(A2:A15=F1)*(C2:C15=F2)))

SIDENOTE: I don't know why this question is tagged Access

A VBA alternative is using ADO and SQL.
The code, uses a SQL query using the pack number in cell L2 and year in cell N2 as input parameters. The comma delimited output is in cell M2
References added:

Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library

Sub Test()
    Dim objADO As ADODB.Connection, objRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strFile As String, strSQL As String, myArr As Variant
    
    Set objADO = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    With objADO
        If Val(Application.Version) < 14 Then
            .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
            .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"
        Else
            .Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
            .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"
        End If
        .Mode = adModeRead
        .Properties("User ID") = "Admin"
        .ConnectionString = strFile
        .Open
    End With
        
    strSQL = "Select [offer] From [Sheet1$] Where [packnum]=" & Range("L2") & " And [mailyear]= " & Range("N2") & " And [packnum] Is Not Null"
    
    With objRS
       .CursorType = adOpenStatic
       .CursorLocation = adUseClient
       .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
       .ActiveConnection = objADO
       .Source = strSQL
       .Open
    End With
    
    myArr = objRS.GetRows(, , "offer")
    Range("M2") = Join(Application.Index(myArr, 0), ", ")
    
    objRS.Close
    
    If objRS.State = adStateOpen Then objRS.Close
    If objADO.State = adStateOpen Then objADO.Close
    
    Set objRS = Nothing
    Set objADO = Nothing
End Sub

.


Can't seem to get this to work. Getting the following error on the .open line for With objADO "Method 'Open' of object'_Connection' Failed". Appreciate your help!

Well, I'm not sure why does not work for you.... My sheet name is Sheet1, may be better to check your sheet name and the references added. It works in my Excel 2010.
